# Email based on the remote I push to

Tags: git

I have a local repo I push to two diffent remotes. Is it possible to configure git so that email_1 is used when I push to remote_1 and email_2 when pushing to remote_2?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an "email" to push? If you're referring to the username and email combination, it's used when you commit. Not when you push. If you're referring to a username used when you authenticate against the remote, it depends on the protocol you're using.

Comment: I deploy to two different sites. The one uses the commit email to point my commits to my account and allows me to hide the email address to the outside (it's github.com). The other displays my email publicly which I'd like to avoid, so I'd like to set a fake mail (dev@null.fake). The problem is I cannot verify dev@null.fake with github. I know an easy solution would be to set a valid email for that purpose, but I'm kind of reluctant to provide users with an email address I would never answer to.

Comment: @AntonGanev: Then you are referring to `user.name` and `user.email` and, as Noufal mentioned, those are saved *into the commit*. They cannot be changed while pushing because pushing only transfers existing history without changing it (changing history while pushing would break so many things....)

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by " uses the commit email to point my commits to my account and allows me to hide the email address to the outside". Can you elaborate a little? Ideally, your application shouldn't use commit metadata in it.

Comment: Changing the authors rewrites history, you wouldn't be able to easily merge back changes between the repos, as the commits in each would be completely different. I'd say: Just use a valid e-mail address. (why publish on github, if you're not interested in feedback at all?)